# decode protocbuf посредством php (или linux shell)

Tags: javascript, php, google-protobuf

здраствуйте, есть готовый скрипт js(browser) который отправляет отправляет вот такой bin текст
playload Content-Type: application/x-protobuf

```
 0
$xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b9bbf8e86d27²
```

ту самую информацию можно перед отправкой посмотреть,

```
trx: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b9bbf8e86d27"
action: "siteConfig"
```

через 

`./protoc --decode-raw < file.bin > file.output`
получаю кашу и не знаю как text-format преобразовать в json

суть вопроса, в том, как на стороне сервера эту информацию преобразить encode/decode,
времени у меня в обрез(немогу сейчас в изучение нырнуть увы), если мало debug информации я все оперативно добавлю, пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно декодировать полностью, а не в сыром виде.

```
protoc --decode header my.proto < b.bin
```

- `header` - это имя класса в прото файле.
- `my.proto` - это собственно сам прото файл

вывод будет более красивым и похожим на то, что Вы ожидаете.

В самом закодированном бинарном файле не сохраняются имена полей, поэтому вместо них можно увидеть только числа-индексы. Если сам прото файл доступен, то эти индексы можно подсмотреть.

Без прото файла декодировать имена полей с бинарных данных не возможно.

Но если у Вас есть приложение, которое использует этот протобаф, можно в самом бинаре очень часто все увидеть.

Comment: дело в том что нет самих файлов *.proto есть только сырой код

Comment: вроде я понял как это сделать на костиле

Comment: без прото файлов или скомпилированных прото файлов это не сделать так просто.

Comment: сейчас есть все числа-индексы и их имена полей, вот теперь задача, создать ответ сервера, реально ли?* есть конкретный шаблон

Comment: уточните задачу. Потому что пока она совсем размыта

Comment: request from client, сервек decode строку на части и сейчас надо так же создать ответ бинарно x-protobuf  клиенту, сейчас думаю через  ./protoc --encode=MESSAGE_TYPE кодировать сообщение

Comment: может спишемся, за помошь я готов заплатить

Comment: я думаю, Вы неверно понимаете концепцию stackoverflow. Кодировать сообщение - Вам нужно просто взять и сгенерировать сериализаторы на свой любимый язык программировать и все будет работать.

Comment: проблему я решил здоровым костилем, спасибо большое подсказали направление ))